# Using `php://temp` or `tempnam` when I write a temporary file in order to upload data into 3rd party network storage

Tags: php, temporary-files

In PHP there are 2 ways in order to create a temporary file:

- Via using php's [`tempnam`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) (example taken from docs)

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, "writing to tempfile");
fclose($handle);

// do here something

unlink($tmpfname);
```

- Via the [`php://temp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) that uses either the memory or a filesystem, depending a threshold (example also from the same page of documentation):

```
$fp = fopen("php://temp/maxmemory:500", 'r+');

fputs($fp, "hello\n");

// Read what we have written.
rewind($fp);
echo stream_get_contents($fp);
```

But I find myself somewhat confused in which approach to decide and what the downsides of each approach mentioned above. Usually, I create a temporary file in cases where I need to upload content into 3rd party internet-based storage such as SFTP or an S3.

So I would like some aid with that.

Comment: They're essentially the same, the only difference really is with `tempnam()` you manually need to unlink the file, and with `php://temp` because it will be cleaned up when you do `stream_get_contents`. The downside to `php://temp` is that  if your upload to the 3rd party fails you might not have the reference to the file handler anymore, so maybe it's best to use `tempnam` and manually unlink the file when you're done with it

Comment: Yeap that does my job.